# Why does `find . -type f` take longer than `find .`?

Tags: find, performance, gnu

It seems like `find` would have to check whether a given path corresponds to a file or directory anyway in order to recursively walk the contents of directories.

Here's some motivation and what I've done locally to convince myself that `find . -type f` really is slower than `find .`. I haven't dug into the GNU find source code yet.

So I'm backing up some of the files in my `$HOME/Workspace` directory, and excluding files that are either dependencies of my projects or version control files.

So I ran the following command which executed quickly

```
% find Workspace/ | grep -v '/vendor\|/node_modules/\|Workspace/sources/\|/venv/\|/.git/' > ws-files-and-dirs.txt
```

`find` piped to `grep` may be bad form, but it seemed like the most direct way to use a negated regex filter.

The following command includes only files in the output of find and took noticeably longer.

```
% find Workspace/ -type f | grep -v '/vendor\|/node_modules/\|Workspace/sources/\|/venv/\|/.git/' > ws-files-only.txt
```

I wrote some code to test the performance of these two commands (with `dash` and `tcsh`, just to rule out any effects the shell might have, even though there shouldn't be any). The `tcsh` results have been omitted because they're essentially the same.

The results I got showed about a 10% performance penalty for `-type f`

Here's the output of the program showing the amount of time taken to execute 1000 iterations of various commands.

```
% perl tester.pl
/bin/sh -c find Workspace/ >/dev/null
82.986582

/bin/sh -c find Workspace/ | grep -v '/vendor\|/node_modules/\|Workspace/sources/\|/venv/\|/.git/' > /dev/null
90.313318

/bin/sh -c find Workspace/ -type f >/dev/null
102.882118

/bin/sh -c find Workspace/ -type f | grep -v '/vendor\|/node_modules/\|Workspace/sources/\|/venv/\|/.git/' > /dev/null

109.872865
```

Tested with

```
% find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

On Ubuntu 15.10

Here's the perl script I used for benchmarking

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw[gettimeofday tv_interval];

my $max_iterations = 1000;

my $find_everything_no_grep = <<'EOF';
find Workspace/ >/dev/null
EOF

my $find_everything = <<'EOF';
find Workspace/ | grep -v '/vendor\|/node_modules/\|Workspace/sources/\|/venv/\|/.git/' > /dev/null
EOF

my $find_just_file_no_grep = <<'EOF';
find Workspace/ -type f >/dev/null
EOF

my $find_just_file = <<'EOF';
find Workspace/ -type f | grep -v '/vendor\|/node_modules/\|Workspace/sources/\|/venv/\|/.git/' > /dev/null
EOF

my @finds = ($find_everything_no_grep, $find_everything,
    $find_just_file_no_grep, $find_just_file);

sub time_command {
    my @args = @_;
    my $start = [gettimeofday()];
    for my $x (1 .. $max_iterations) {
        system(@args);
    }
    return tv_interval($start);
}

for my $shell (["/bin/sh", '-c']) {
    for my $command (@finds) {
        print "@$shell $command";
        printf "%s\n\n", time_command(@$shell, $command);
    }
}
```

Comment: *It seems like `find` would have to check whether a given path corresponds to a file or directory anyway in order to recursively walk the contents of directories.* - it would have to check if it's a directory, it would not have to check whether it is a file. There are other entry types: named pipes, symbolic links, block special devices, sockets... So although it may have done the check already to see if it's a directory, it doesn't mean it knows whether it's a regular file.

Comment: busybox find, applied to random directory with 4,3k dirs and 2,8k files run same time with `-type f` and without it. But at first time Linux kernel loaded it into cache and very first find was slower.

Comment: My first guess was that the `-type f` option caused `find` to call `stat()` or `fstat()` or whatever in order to find out if the file name corresponded to a file, a directory, a symlink, etc etc. I did an `strace` on a `find . ` and a `find . -type f` and  the trace was almost identical, differing only in the `write()` calls that had directory names in them. So, I don't know, but I want to know the answer.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but there's a `time` builtin command to see how long a command takes to execute, you didn't really need to write a custom script to test.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GNU find has an optimization which can be applied to `find .` but not to `find . -type f`: if it knows that none of the remaining entries in a directory are directories, then it doesn't bother to determine the file type (with the `stat` system call) unless one of the search criteria requires it. Calling `stat` can take measurable time since the information is typically in the inode, in a separate location on the disk, rather than in the containing directory.

How does it know? Because the link count on a directory indicates how many subdirectories it has. On typical Unix filesystems, a directory's link count is 2 plus the number of directories: one for the directory's entry in its parent, one for the `.` entry, and one for the `..` entry in each subdirectory.

The `-noleaf` option tells `find` not to apply this optimization. This is useful if `find` is invoked on some filesystem where directory link counts don't follow the Unix convention.

Comment: Is this still pertinent? Looking at the `find` source, it simply uses the `fts_open()` and `fts_read()` calls nowadays.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Has this changed in recent versions? I haven't checked the source, but experimentally, version  4.4.2 in Debian stable does optimize `stat` calls when it doesn't need them due to directory link counts, and the `-noleaf` option is documented in the manual.

Comment: It optimizes `stat` even in the `fts...` version - it passes the appropriate flag for that to the `fts_open` call. But what I am not sure is still pertinent is the check with the number of links. It checks instead whether the returned fts record has one of the "directory" flags. It may be that `fts_read` itself checks the links to set that flag, but `find` doesn't. You can see whether your version relies on `fts` by calling `find --version`.

Comment: @Gilles, Would `find` theoretically be able to determine when all the all of the entries in a directory are directories too and use that information?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet In theory yes, but the source code (I've now checked) doesn't do that, presumably because it's a much rarer case.